# putInt Java equivalent method in Swift

Tags: java, swift

I am looking for a Java method `putInt` equivalent in Swift and for Java method `System.arraycopy`.

I have tried with data in Swift but get the wrong result:

```
ByteBuffer Len = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
Len.putInt(mLen);                    // 0x00112233 order
mBlock[mLen1] = Len.get(0);
```

`mLen` is an integer.

What would be equivalent in Swift and for another method:

```
System.arraycopy(bData, 0, mBlock, 0, mLen);
```

It's giving an array out of bounds error.

Comment: There's no Swift code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`ByteBuffer`](https://apple.github.io/swift-nio/docs/current/NIO/Structs/ByteBuffer.html#/) in the NIO library in Swift. The `writeInteger` and `getBytes` methods are very similar to `putInt` and `get` in the Java `ByteBuffer`.

However, it seems like you don't need to use a byte buffer here at all. You seem to just want to get the most significant 8 bits of `mLen`, which can be done with bit shifting and masking. In Swift:

```
// Assuming mBlock is [Int], mLen is Int
mBlock[mLen] = (mLen >> Int.bitWidth - 8) & 0xFF
```

`System.arraycopy` is basically slicing an array and assigning it to another array, which can be done with `replaceSubrange` in Swift:

```
mBlock.replaceSubrange(0..<mLen, with: bData)
```

Comment: mBlock is Data and this is the java code  mBlock[memLen1] = bLen.get(0) I am trying to get work where bLen is a byte buffer.